# Touchpad click again after single click in 1 second, but another user no problem

Tags: mouse

My touchpad click again after single click in 1 second,  but another user in my ubuntu 16.04 is no problem.

It have starting on 14.04 and still going on 16.04 because I use the same /home.

Answer (score 0):

I don't known "what's time I turned it on." I'm sorry.

Topic resolved.

[image: Turn Hover Click off. That's all.]